# Accessing the SD-Card in an Android Application

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing an Android Application, that will open and save .txt files.
In order to make it easy to read external .txt files i want to make sure, that they are saved in the app's folder on the SD-Card.
Unfortunately i am only able to access /storage/emulated/0.

I already tried 2 different possibilites:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
getExternalFilesDir("MyFileStorage")
```

They both lead to /storage/emulated/0 on the internal storage.
Does anyone know how i can access the app's folder on the SD Card of my Smartphone (USB-Debugging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that they are saved in the app's folder on the SD-Card

By default, apps do not have a directory on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

On Android 4.4+, you are welcome to [use `getExternalFilesDirs()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)) (note the `s` on the end). If this returns a list with 2+ entries, the first one will be on external storage, and the others will be on removable storage.

> I already tried 2 different possibilites... They both lead to /storage/emulated/0 on the internal storage

Those point to what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Answer (score -2):

Apps don't come with a folder on the external storage by default. You will need to create a folder for your app like this:

```
String folder_main = "YourAppName";

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();
}
```

Remember that you need to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your `AndroidManifest.xml` to access the SD card (and use the permissions model introduced in Android 6.0 for newer devices).

Comment: This code has nothing to do with the SD card on the vast majority of Android devices.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() leads again to /storage/emulated/0. Therefore i am creating a folder on my internal storage.
I have the permission to write on external storage though (i even checked it in the settings of my phone).